# Eventos de poligonos no google maps com javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ionic3

Estou precisando capturar o evento de `DWELL`, `ENTER`, `LEAVE` do poligonos, ja conseguir adiciona-los no mapa com o seguinte código:

```
this.map.addPolygon({
    points: geofence,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    draggable: true,
    geodesic: true
});
```

Agora não estou sabendo adicionar para ouvir eventos de entrada, saida e movimentações dentro desta área.

Como fazer isto ??

Utilizo a versão mais recente do `google maps` o `v3`. Está sendo desenvolvido no `ionic 3`

Preciso basicamente fazer isto

https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

no javascript

Comment: Os eventos são eventos de usuário?

Comment: @N.Dias Não o próprio sistema movimenta o marker

Answer (score 0):

Para adicionar eventos num polígono, você pode guardar a referência ao polígono e atribuir um evento usando `addListener`

Por exemplo:

```
var polygonCoords = [
    {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190},
    {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
    {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757},
    {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190}
];

//Guarda a referencia ao polígono.
var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
   paths: polygonCoords,
   strokeColor: '#FF0000',
   strokeOpacity: 0.8,
   strokeWeight: 2,
   fillColor: '#FF0000',
   fillOpacity: 0.35
}); 

//EVENTO
polygon.addListener('mouseout', function() {
   //Faça algo aqui
})
```

Link do exemplo completo: [click aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/6qc4640q/)

Usei como exemplo o evento **mouseout**. Aqui neste [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events?hl=pt-br) você pode identificar todos os eventos possíveis:

Comment: Seu exemplo funciona bem quando o usuário tem um evento, porém no meu caso o evento é executado automaticamente. Eu até fiz um exemplo comparando as localizações do polígono com a localização que enviei, porém ficou algo muito inconstante e inseguro.